Forward reference vs rvalue
Minimal implementation:
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
auto universal_ref(T&& arr)
{
    for (auto && v : arr)
        std::cout << v << '\n';
}

template <typename T, size_t N>
auto not_universal_ref(std::array<T, N>&& arr)
{
    for (auto && v : arr)
        std::cout << v << '\n';
}

Question:
which strategy could be used to transform it into an universal reference while still ensuring the argument must be an array?

This is no dupe. If you want I can concentrate the question on the current question 2.

I know it is an rvalue in not_universal_ref, I just don't find a nice reference on it.

T&& arr + enable_if or requires depending on whether C++20 is available.

Well, the reference is what NathanOliver linked. Here, a specific quote from top answer: "A forwarding reference is an rvalue reference to a cv-unqualified template parameter.". std::array is not a template parameter, it's a class that happens to be parameterised on template arguments.

@deponovo https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references
There are really only two cases where such references can be created.

Yes. It just feels counter-intuitive that by simply having T you get a universal reference, but not with the array one. The intuition I mean is that led by the replacement of the template arguments by actual types. At first sight std::array<T, N>&& does not look that different from T&& if you'd concentrate on them after replacing T and N by actual types.

You can require that T is some std::array<U,N> via std::enable_if:
template <typename T> struct is_array : std::false_type {};

template <typename U,std::size_t N> struct is_array<std::array<U,N>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<is_array<std::decay_t<T>>::value> universal_ref(T&& arr)
{
    for (auto && v : arr)
        std::cout << v << '\n';
}

Live Demo
Afaik nothing in the language specifies what a forwarding reference is. It is merely template argument deduction and reference collapsing rules which govern how T is deduced when you call universal_ref. Hence, std::array<T,N>&& in your other example is not a forwarding reference, the type of the reference is not deduced nor is reference collapsing applied, it is simply a rvalue reference.

This is what I was talking about. Thank you for the example.

Gone tag the question with SFINAE and concepts (although I am currently working with C++17... But that makes the thread more generic, with concepts I mean)

@depono not sure what the majority opinion is, imho tagging SFINAE on the question is misleading. Your question by itself has nothing to do with SFINAE. An answer could have used concepts and it would be a good answer but no sfinae at all. Imho question tags should not (try to) anticipate the answer. There is no sfinae in your question, so why tag it? (and same for concepts). Though, I know others disagree with this

Seems to be a fair argument. I'll leave them for now to be subjected to additional critics, if others share the same opinion I'll remove them.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai Concepts are sfinae (a failed requirement is a substitution failure). A non-sfinae solution is to have four overloads (const) std::array<T, N>(&/&&)

@Artyer anyhow, I also wouldnt tag the question overloading ;)

Still in the context of this question, what is wrong with the following variation that does not compile for arr lvalues: universal_ref(T&& arr, typename T::value_type elem)?

If the typename T::value_type is declared in the list of template type params (ie template <typename T&&, typename ElemT = typename T::value_type>), then it works as I need but I am failing to understand why.

@deponovo unclear what you mean with "it works as I need". template <typename T> auto universal_ref(T&& arr) works too

@deponov oh I missed the previous comment. If you have a follow up quesiton you better open a new question

@depnovo does not work here https://godbolt.org/z/ofcMsqbro

Here you go.
